# can't Access hidden field or params in controller

Tags: grails, gsp

I am passing the params as well as customer obj to gsp page from controller. for eg

```
render(view:"finish", params: params, model:[customer: customer])
```

The finish.gsp prints the form fields using both params and customer object passed. eg `${params.name}` or `${customer.name}`. On the finish page when done button is selected, I want to pass the params or customer object values to save the customer object. So I am setting the hidden field on finish.gsp.

```
  <g:actionSubmit action="save" value="Done" class="button1" params ="${customer}"/>
  <g:hiddenField name="kbc" value="${params}" />
</g:form>`
```

I am able to see the values on save action method for `println params.kbc` as

```
[contactBy:email, appointmentDate:Wed Oct 24 14:54:00 CDT 2012, appointmentDate_day:24, appointmentDate_hour:14, sentReminder:on, appointmentDate_month:10, emailAddress:jaimataji@jaimataji.com, lookingFor:0, appointmentDate_year:2012, appointmentDate_minute:54, _action_finish:Next, myGroup:0, _sentReminder:, description:test, name:abc, contactNo:7777777777, action:index, controller:customer]`</b>
```

But when I try to access `params.kbc.name` it throws me error saying

```
No such property: name for class: java.lang.String
```

I do not know where I am going wrong. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I believe `params` object don't try to parse/convert internal structures of passed data. It's just a http request parameter. So, you can have only a `String`.

If you need to convert `String` to `Map`, you should write your own converter. Seems that it's not what you want.

Or instead, if you need `params.kbc.name`, you can pass it as `<g:hiddenField name="kbc.name" value="${params.name}" />` Same for other fields.

Comment: Ok, that's one approach but if there are more form fields, it ends up having many hidden fields. is there a way I can pass the model customer object ? I am  passing it as an hidden field but I do not see it in params obj?

Comment: do you really need all fields? you can also pass only `id` field, and load then object from database

Comment: Yes I will need all the fields as values collected from form are displayed in next page before saving. If the obj was saved then id alone would be suffice to load it.